# SQL MailMessage Remove body of message

Tags: sql, email, object

We have an application that the stores emails in a MailMessage table in SQL Server as you can imagine the users never delete anything and I was wondering if there was a way to blow out the actual body of the message but leave the reference in the database that a message was sent.

The database stores the message in IdMessageObj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to store a reference that a mail was sent you can create a Mail Template folder in your app and store the type of mail sent based on the template ID along with datetime and userid (to whom mail was sent).

Please let me know if your requirement is different.

Comment: Really would like to be able to clear out just the message body for old emails

Comment: are you looking to flush out the column data which store message body ?

Comment: how about this sql script Update MailMessage set IdMessageObj = ''